# Get `next/image` working with CSS Grid Full Bleed Layout?

Tags: css, next.js, css-grid, mdxjs, nextjs-image

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://joshwcomeau.com/css/full-bleed/).

Here's the TL;DR:

```css
.grid--wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr min(65ch, calc(100% - 64px)) 1fr;
    column-gap: 32px;
}

.grid--wrapper > *,
.header {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.full-bleed {
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

It follows Medium-like design with images bleeding towards the edges of the browser.

And it has a `full-bleed` class for Image:

```css
.full-bleed {
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

I am really not sure how to make my `next/image` work with this kind of stuff?

My `Img.tsx` file looks like:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
type ImageProps = any

export const Img = ({ className = '', ...props }: ImageProps) => (
    <Image className={`${className} full-bleed`} width="100%" {...props} />
)
```

And my `components/mdx/index.ts` looks like:

```
import { H1 } from '@/components/mdx/H1'
import { H2 } from '@/components/mdx/H2'
import { H3 } from '@/components/mdx/H3'
import { H4 } from '@/components/mdx/H4'
import { H5 } from '@/components/mdx/H5'
import { H6 } from '@/components/mdx/H6'
import { Img } from '@/components/mdx/Img'
import { Pre } from '@/components/mdx/Pre'
import { PreCode } from '@/components/mdx/PreCode'
import { P } from './P'

export const MDXComponents = {
    h1: H1,
    h2: H2,
    h3: H3,
    h4: H4,
    h5: H5,
    h6: H6,
    p: P,
    img: Img,
    pre: Pre,
    'pre.code': PreCode,
}
```

My `.mdx` files contain normal HTML `img` tags which will use `Img` component as written above (which internally uses `next/image`).

How do I get full-bleed layout when I don't have a height? I can't even get `layout="fill"` to work properly. It just overlaps images on top of each other.

Any ideas?

Comment: So I assume `grid-column: 1 / 4;` doesn't work too? Does this throw any errors in relation to your path?

Comment: Maybe this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mor10/pen/xdYoNO?editors=1100) will help

Comment: @ra.design no errors, it's CSS. CSS doesn't throw any errors. Or any other errors.

Comment: @SionaFernandes i think that codepen is different from what i am trying to achieve. my `img` tag that comes from `next/image` is wrapped in 2 `div`'s & the codepen you mentioned has just a top-level `img`. if i replace `next/image` with regular `img`, my code works just fine :)

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Can you show us the rendered markup?

Comment: @ra.design check the codesandbox here → https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-blog-css-grid-ougks?file=/src/components/Post.js ... u just need to edit the `Image` tag in `src/components/Post.js` to `img` to see the full-bleed effect...try opening the codesandbox in a new window if it doesn't show it in the same window

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Your codesandbox is set to read-only, I can't edit it.

Comment: @ra.design u can fork it & edit it & share a link with me so I can fork it. I don't think they allow to write on the free plan :)

Comment: Did you solve this? FYI mdx wraps `img` tags in a `p` tag which means that your fullbleed class would need to be on the div. Doesn't solve the issue with Image needing a width and a height though

Comment: @blackhaj nope, I didn't find an answer. But I am adding `img` tag directly in `MDXComponents.ts` which references `next/image` directly. I am not sure what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to https://dev.to/tanahmed/next-image-make-image-fill-available-space-272o

All I had to do was change my markup to:

```
import Image, { ImageProps } from 'next/image'

export const Img = ({ className = '', ...props }: ImageProps) => (
    <div className="unset-img full-bleed">
        <Image className={`${className} custom-img`} layout="fill" {...props} />
    </div>
)
```

And change my CSS to:

```css
.grid--wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr min(65ch, calc(100% - 64px)) 1fr;
    column-gap: 32px;
}

.grid--wrapper > *,
.header {
    grid-column: 2;
}

.full-bleed {
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.half-bleed {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.wrapper {
    width: min(60ch, calc(100% - 64px));
}

.custom-img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
}

.unset-img {
    width: 100%;
}
.unset-img > div {
    position: unset !important;
}
```